# how to make new variable in python while output print

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
output=

Sign in to Twitter
Visit someone's profile
Saved search
Promote this Tweet
Block
Tweet with location
Spread the Location
Your list
Create a new list

Copy Tweet link
Embed this Tweet
```

and i want make to one variable="*Sign in to Twitter,Visit someone's profile,Saved search,Promote this Tweet,Block,Tweet with location,Spread the Location,Your list,Create a new list,Copy Tweet link,Embed this Tweet*"

Comment: Can you make your post clear?

Comment: are you asking how to store the string with new lines ? are you trying store an array of string ? please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: yes sir, i want to trying store an array of string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is it You want?

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import os
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':

    var = '''
    Sign in to Twitter
    Visit someone's profile
    Saved search
    Promote this Tweet
    Block
    Tweet with location
    Spread the Location
    Your list
    Create a new list

    Copy Tweet link
    Embed this Tweet
    '''
   output = var.split('\n')
    print (var)
    print(output)
```

output print:

> ['', 'Sign in to Twitter', "Visit someone's profile", 'Saved search', 'Promote this Tweet', 'Block', 'Tweet with location', 'Spread the Location', 'Your list', 'Create a new list', '', 'Copy Tweet link', 'Embed this Tweet', '    ']

Comment: how to make output  in python sir?